# How to display null if join condition is not met

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table `tbl_expenseLimit` which I use to get the `Limit` for a given combination of variables.

**tbl_expenselimit**

```
+------+---------+----------+---------+-------+----------+
| SrNo | ExpType | Location | Expense | Limit | empgrade |
+------+---------+----------+---------+-------+----------+
|    1 | ERA     | Metro    |       1 |   250 | A        |
|    2 | ERA     | Metro    |       2 |   500 | A        |
|    3 | ERA     | Metro    |       3 |  5000 | A        |
+------+---------+----------+---------+-------+----------+
```

If `ExpType` in my main table is ERA, `Location` is Metro, `Expense` is 1  and `empgrade` is 'A' then `Limit` would be 250.

If any of the condition does not match, for example: If `ExpType` is ERA, `Expense` is 1 ,`empgrade` is 'A' but `Location` is Non-Metro then `Limit` should be `NULL` . Similarly if all conditions match but empgrade is 'B' (which is not present in `tbl_expenselimit` table it should return `NULL` for `Limit`

```
select other.srno,VoucherId,other.ExpType, lmt.Limit 
from tbl_voucherotherexpense other 
left join tbl_TypesOfExpenses expensemst 
on other.expense=expensemst.srno 
left   join tbl_expenseLimit lmt 
on (other.Expense=lmt.Expense 
and other.ExpType=lmt.ExpType     
and (( lmt.location is not null  
and other.location=lmt.location) or 1=1))   
where voucherid='C0000004' and lmt.empgrade='a'
```

The join between `tbl_voucherotherexpense` and `tbl_TypesOfExpenses` will always find a match.  So its just `tbl_expenseLimit` that needs to be focused on.

The query that I have written is wrong. It does not achieve what I want. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Suppose in my main table  `ExpType` is *ERA*, `Location` is *Metro*, `Expense` is *2* but `empgrade` is *B* then output should be :

```
+------+-----------+---------+-------+
| srno | VoucherId | ExpType | Limit |
+------+-----------+---------+-------+
|    4 | C0000004  | ERA     | NULL  |
+------+-----------+---------+-------+
```

or if 
in my main table  `ExpType` is *ERA*, `Location` is *Metro*,  `empgrade` is *A* but `Expense` is *12* then output should still be the same as above.

Comment: Can you include your expected output as your description is a bit unclear?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please see my edit. Hope things are more clear now.

Comment: you did not mention which table is your main table. could you please give your other two tables with data as your tbl_expenselimit table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the conditions that refer to the table you're left joining i.e. `lmt` should go in the `on`, which, unlike the `where` clause, won't remove rows where the condition isn't matched:

```
select other.srno,VoucherId,other.ExpType, lmt.Limit 
from tbl_voucherotherexpense other left join tbl_TypesOfExpenses expensemst on other.expense=expensemst.srno 
left join tbl_expenseLimit lmt 
    on other.Expense=lmt.Expense 
    and other.ExpType=lmt.ExpType 
    and other.location=lmt.location   
    and lmt.empgrade='a' 
where voucherid='C0000004'
```

Comment: You have omitted ` and lmt.empgrade='a'` part. If I include this part in my where condition it would return no rows. The `tbl_expenseLimit ` , what I want is that if any of the conditions related to `tbl_expenseLimit `  is not met it should give me `NULL` for limit. Now that also includes `lmt.empgrade='a'` in where conidition

Comment: @Arbaaz see update. `lmt.empgrade='a'` needs to go in `on` not `where`